# Как правильно передать аргументы командной строки в программу

Tags: c, cmd, c++

Пожалуйста не ругайте)

Не знаю как адекватно подавать значения и чтобы компилятор понимал
изначально условие вот такое:

> Определить количество положительныых
> элементов главной диагонали
>         превышающих заданное значение.
>
> `а в параметры передаем: 10 0 5 5`

проблема тут?)

> max=argv[1];
>     col=argv[2];
>     ssize=argv[3];
>     ksize=argv[4];

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

int func(int * array, int  dim1, int  dim2)
{        
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i< dim1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<dim2; j++)
            {
                array[i * dim1 + j] =rand()%25-5;
                cout<<array[i * dim2 + j]<<"   ";
              }
        cout << '\n';

    }  
    return *array;

 }

 int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{   
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

int max,col,ssize,ksize;
max=atoi(argv[1]);
col=atoi(argv[2]);
ssize=atoi(argv[3]);
ksize=atoi(argv[4]);

    int m[ssize][ksize];

        func((int*)m,ssize,ksize);
        cout<<"максимальное число"<<max<<endl;

    for (int i=0;i<ssize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"m[i][i]="<<m[i][i]<<endl;
             if((m[i][i]>=0) && (m[i][i]>max)) col++;
     }
     cout<<"Кол-во чисел больше нуля и больше заданного максимума="<<col<<endl;

}
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь присвоить переменным типа int буквенные массивы. Даже если бы это сработало и char перевелись бы в int, там были бы неверные значения. вам нужна функция [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

argv - это `char**`. Как так присваивать значения указателей на строку целым переменным?!)
С помощью функции `atoi()` нужно перевести `char* -> int`.

Comment: Программа зависает и windows предлагает завершить работу ей...

Comment: @Анатолийй, а Вы распечатайте `ssize` и `ksize` **перед** `int m[ssize][ksize];`.

Учтите, каждый int занимает 4 байта, 1000 х 1000 это уже 10^6, а в стек помещается, скорее всего, только пара мегабайт.

Comment: @Анатолийй
Вы выходите за границы буфера. В C/C++ массивы индексируются с нуля.

     int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
    {   
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

        int max,col,ssize,ksize;
        max=atoi(argv[0]);
        col=atoi(argv[1]);
        ssize=atoi(argv[2]);
        ksize=atoi(argv[3]);
        .............

Comment: @Free_ze, argv[0] - это путь и имя исполняемого файла, параметры начинаются с 1. У TC здесь правильно.

Comment: @paulgri да, точно, сглупил)